# Session/EntityManager and (EntityManagerFactory) is closed following update to Spring Batch 5.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-batch, kubernetes-cronjob

We have a batch job we use for reporting that was running fine prior to upgrading spring boot / batch in our project.  Following general upgrade advice we have migrated our batch tables and upgrades where applicable deprecated cursor classes.

We are now able to run the batch job successfully locally with SELECTs hitting our Hibernate / Database, but this doesn't happen when we deploy in a development environment.

Class which defines the report that is failing is here...

https://github.com/ministryofjustice/hmpps-interventions-service/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/uk/gov/justice/digital/hmpps/hmppsinterventionsservice/reporting/ndmis/performance/NdmisPerformanceReportJobConfiguration.kt

Error we are seeing seems to be caused by IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed (Then later EntityManagerFactory is closed when saving the batch job status), but we are unable to determine why this is an issue on our development environment but not locally.

Is anyone able to offer any advice please?  Is there a bug we should be aware of?

Deploy to a development environment and run the job from a cronjob call.  We were expecting successful report output but are seeing errors on database access due to closed EntityManager/EntityManagerFactory

Comment: What is the difference between the dev and local environments? When, exactly, does the error happen? Can you share a stacktrace?

Comment: We got to the bottom of the problem, seems we weren't seeing the exception, it related to Lazy loading of entities used in the report, the exception we were seeing was secondary.   We are still having issues with the new JobBuilder and StepBuilder but that appears to be a more minor issue - we have worked around with the deprecated versions. for now.  Thanks for looking Mahmoud.